# Add string representation of a LinkedHashMap<String,String>

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a `String` that has been constructed from another `LinkedHashMap` using `toString` method, and I want to do the reverse in creating another `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` with this `String` representation of the previous `LinkedHashMap`.

Is it possible withing using `String` splits and manually doing it in a loop calling `LinkedHashMap.put()` ?

I think this could work?

LinkedHashMap params = new LinkedHashMap();

```
String[] split = paramsString2.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String[] nameValue = split[i].split("=");
    params.put(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);

}

return params;
```

Comment: I think yes, why not. You just have to write a convert method.

Comment: What does the String look like?

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample string that was constructed from the Map.

Comment: It works with LinkedHashMap, as the order is preserved and you will end up with same LinkedHashMap when converted from the string. If it was HashMap, I think that you might end up with a different map.

Comment: I think there is no standard approach to reconstruct the map from the string returned by `toString` (other than approach you have given). What is your use case? Can't you just serialize the map and deserialize it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the string is of the form

```
key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3
```

Yes, it is possible. Use `string.split(";")` to separate the map entries into an array.

Then loop through the array, and for each entry, use `string.split("=")` to separate the key from the value.

Then add the key and value to the new `LinkedHashMap`:

```
String[] parts = entry.split("=");
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);   //parts[0] is the key, parts[1] is the value
```

Comment: Yea the string looks like that

Comment: Note, though, that semicolons or equals signs in keys or values won't be escaped, so some maps won't be convertible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible, but why should you do such horrible stuff?

Anyway, yes it is possible, you could also use the guava library to accomplish such a job.
[guava-library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)

Comment: Because in Android, when you pass a serializable LinkedHashMap thats in order, it messes it up and converts it to a HashMap :(

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add that to the question!